# Notification Service from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, service, notifications

How make notification?
How to check the date of the news and show notification when there is news?
Can service get SharedPref from `Fragment` and check and then make notification or no?

`TabFragment1.class` code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = object.getString("title");
            String desc = object.getString("description");
            String imageUrl = object.getString("urlToImage");
            String articleUrl = object.getString("url");
            String newsdata = object.getString("publishedAt");

            sPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
            ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, newsdata);
            ed.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            News news = new News(title, desc, imageUrl, articleUrl);
            myAdapter.addNews(news);

            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Notification Service code:

```
public class Notification extends Service {
    String datanews;
    String titlenotif;
    String destnotif;
    MyAsynk asynk;
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    String checker;
    SharedPreferences sPref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 0, 1800000); //тикаем каждые 30 мinute без задержки 1800000
    }

    class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
            String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
            checker = sPref.getString(savedText, "0");

            if(datanews != checker){
                asynk = new MyAsynk();
                asynk.execute();
                createNotification(getApplicationContext());//пушим уведомление
            } else {
                asynk = new MyAsynk();
                asynk.execute();
            }
        }
    }

    class MyAsynk extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,StringBuilder> {
        @Override
        protected StringBuilder doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String key = "0aa2713d5a1a4aad9a914c9294f6a22b";
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=" + key);
                URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
                uc.connect();
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
                int ch;
                while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) ch);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            return stringBuilder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = object.getString("title");
                    String desc = object.getString("description");
                    String newsdata = object.getString("publishedAt");
                    datanews = newsdata;
                    titlenotif = title;
                    destnotif = desc;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    private void createNotification(Context context) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder ncBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        ncBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{500});
        ncBuilder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 3000, 3000);
        ncBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        ncBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        ncBuilder.setContentTitle(titlenotif + "");
        ncBuilder.setContentText(destnotif + "");
        ncBuilder.setTicker("You have news!");
        ncBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.news_icon);
        ncBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        manager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),ncBuilder.build());
    }
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes `Service` can read `SharedPreference` and can make notification.

If I understood correctly, you need to create the notification in the `onPostExecute` function of your `MyAsynk` class.

So you may try adding an public attribute in your `AsyncTask` like this.

```
class MyAsynk extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,StringBuilder> {

    public boolean showNotification;

    // .. Other functions
}
```

Now in your `UpdateTimerTask`

```
if(datanews != checker){
    asynk = new MyAsynk();
    asynk.showNotification = true;
    asynk.execute();
} else {
    asynk = new MyAsynk();
    asynk.showNotification = false;
    asynk.execute();
}
```

Now in the `onPostExecute` of your `MyAsynk` class, you need to check the boolean and create the notification accordingly.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = object.getString("title");
            String desc = object.getString("description");
            String newsdata = object.getString("publishedAt");
            datanews = newsdata;
            titlenotif = title;
            destnotif = desc;
        }

        // Create notification here on demand
        if(showNotification) createNotification(getApplicationContext);
    }
    catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

**Update**

From comment

> Maybe somehow it is necessary to check the date of the publication of
>   news, verify it with the current date and display a notice .. So you
>   need to show the notice only when there is news

If you're planning to track the new news from client side only, you might have to do a lot of coding including keeping a local storage and checking each time if a new news arrived or not. You need to have a server-side implementation here I guess. Which will send you a push notification when a new news is received. The server should handle the syncing and other mechanisms.

Comment: it displays a notification but without stopping
I want to notifu user only when there was news..

Comment: Maybe somehow it is necessary to check the date of the publication of news, verify it with the current date and display a notice .. So you need to show the notice only when there is news

Comment: Please see the updated answer and upvote if the answer was helpful.

Comment: oh thx.. I cant make notification as I want by using timer that will check date of news and make notification if date was changed